# Are there any significant implications to re-design a settings page?

Tags: forms, settings

We're doing a migration for some of our settings pages for our website at my current job and we're also trying to hit an external deadline. The way the current settings pages are laid out is a tabbed format. You press a tab and it opens up the account info settings like username and password. you hit another tab and it opens up the subscriptions settings (it's literally only 1 setting). You hit another tab and open up 1 setting.

I was thinking of minimizing work and putting all the settings on 1 page for the initial phase of the migration (it's about 1 full page and 1/4 page scroll down (however, more in mobile devices) and then iterating on the design and UX later. Now, let's keep in mind this is a settings page on our website and not our main product. (the simplified new settings page looks like the screenshot below.

[image]

Will this new layout of 1 page for settings have a significant impact on our users in terms of them unsubscribing from our service or deciding not to use our service if they newly signed up?

For more context, here's a close example of what the current settings looks like below --I can't post the actual design we have.

[image]

Comment: For as far I can judge the situation, I would make the change if that keeps the deadline realistic. There won't be too many settings on the page to make a real impact on the user experience. It may even improve it since people don't have to think about the category a setting belongs to, which makes all settings more discoverable.

Comment: I hope you are not actually storing credit card details, or any other financial information on your own servers? Because that won't end well if you are.

Comment: @musefan how is this relevant to the question

Comment: @jazZRo that's what i was thinking too, thanks

Comment: I think it's an improvement! much easier to get an overview of all the settings, rather than having to click 4 times to find something. Unsubscribing should not be a concern, if people can't find it easily you only get annoyed people (bad for your brand name) and increased effort for the support team to deal with them.. I would think about the order of your sections though, maybe put unsubscribe at the bottom?

Comment: @duxfox-- it is relevant because in your question you show that you might be, so it is worth mentioning. Perhaps what you are trying to say is "how does that answer my question?" to which my response would be "it doesn't, hence the comment and not an answer". A lot of people don't realise that there are serious consequences to storing financial information like this, so I think it's something worth commenting. Even if you are already aware, the comment might prove useful to somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

Redesigning the Settings page in the manner you describe would likely not have a negative impact on your signups or retention rates. What might become challenging for your users is if they set up a large number of Notifications or Subusers. If they have to immediately remove one of 1,000 Subusers but there are 125 Notifications to scroll through first, that might become an obstacle.

A third option might be to reduce the number of tabs, but keep them for Notifications and Subusers. Keeping the tabs at the top will speed up tasks related to those areas.

Answer (score -1):

I think there are no any significant implications. The reason is that user doesn't matter on settings design in comparison with main goal of the whole website design. Conversely, website owner pay much more attention to settings design because its goal is to gather important, reliable and valid data from user.